# Google host email failure - diagnostic code smtp; 550-5.1.1

Tags: gmail, google-workspace, google-apps-email

I'm having difficulties figuring out exactly why this particular email address has stopped working. The domain is hosted by HostGator, but the associated email account is hosted by Google.

This is the error message received when trying to send an email to the email address in question:

> This is the mail system at host gateway.websitewelcome.com.
>
> I'm sorry to have to inform you that your message could not be
>   delivered to one or more recipients. It's attached below.
>
> For further assistance, please send mail to postmaster.
>
> If you do so, please include this problem report. You can delete your
>   own text from the attached returned message.
>
> ```
>               The mail system
> ```
>
> <###@###.com>: host
>   ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.com[173.194.77.27]    said: 550-5.1.1 The email account
>   that you tried to reach does not exist.    Please try 550-5.1.1
>   double-checking the recipient's email address for    typos or
>   550-5.1.1 unnecessary spaces. Learn more at 550 5.1.1
>   http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?answer=6596
>   r10si31186012oef.53 - gsmtp (in reply to RCPT TO command)
>   Reporting-MTA: dns; gateway.websitewelcome.com X-Postfix-Queue-ID:
>   E5A2529629D6 X-Postfix-Sender: rfc822; alex@frshstudio.com
>   Arrival-Date: Sat,  9 Feb 2013 18:34:21 -0600 (CST)
>
> Final-Recipient: rfc822; ###@###.com Action:
>   failed Status: 5.1.1 Remote-MTA: dns; ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.com
>   Diagnostic-Code: smtp; 550-5.1.1 The email account that you tried to
>   reach does    not exist. Please try 550-5.1.1 double-checking the
>   recipient's email    address for typos or 550-5.1.1 unnecessary
>   spaces. Learn more at 550 5.1.1
>   http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?answer=6596
>   r10si31186012oef.53 - gsmtp

Any ideas what could be causing this and how to fix it?
The [support page given by Google](http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?answer=6596) indicates that there are typos in the address, and I cannot find any.

**ETA:** HostGator tech support indicated that perhaps there is something going on with the WISE server, but I have not idea how to follow up on this.

Comment: Any and all help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Add more details like if you are the administrator of the Google Apps domain and have access to the domain directory.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about administration of email servers.